# При записи данных в БД Access в Windows Form пишет ошибку System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: "Ошибка синтаксиса в инструкции INSERT INTO."

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

```
public void InsertUser(string username, string password)
{
    using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        string query = "INSERT INTO Users_db (Username, Password) VALUES (@Username, @Password)";
        using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, connection))
        {
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", username);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", password);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

В Access у меня таблица называется Users_db, столбики Username и Password, и присвоен тип Короткий текст. Также есть столбик UserID, но он задан ключевым и на нём стоит счётчик.
Ошибка выдаётся на строчке command.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: `"INSERT INTO Users_db ([Username], [Password]) VALUES (?, ?)"`

Comment: [Working with parameter placeholders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/configuring-parameters-and-parameter-data-types#working-with-parameter-placeholders)